# Ruby Custom Super Initialization

Tags: ruby, xmlrpcclient

Here is my situation:

- `XMLRPC::Client` has a proxy constructor, `new3`, that takes a hash of options. It takes out the individual values to then delegate the construction to the default initializer, `initialize`
- I am deriving from `XMLRPC::Client`. I want a class that *is* `XMLRPC::Client` but with some added functionality.
- I want to be able to instantiate this **derived** class using a hash of options as well. This means that in my derived class' initializer, I have to somehow instantiate `super` using the `new3` proxy constructor.

**My Question Is** if this is possible. If not, then is the only way to solve this is to practically 'copy and paste' the code within the `XMLRPC::Client.new3` method into my derived class' constructor?

The **reason** I'm asking this is simply to see if there is a way of solving this problem, since there is this recurring theme of DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) within the Ruby community. But of course, if this is the only way, it wont kill me.

Comment: Wow, uh, can you clean up the question so it reflects the question you want to ask? You're asking a couple questions now: "my question is", "I will restate my question", "My Question is". It's ok to gut it if that's what it takes, just keep it on the same topic and generally on the same question.

Comment: @Greg: I did clean up the question, it's just that I did a 'strikethrough' on the previous body of the question instead of flat out removing it in case people were reading it. I'm removing it now :) I really do hope you didn't attempt to read through the striked-out portion of the question, haha, it was striked out for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am only posting an answer supplement the other answers by showing you how XMLRPC's code is written

```
def new3(hash={})

      # convert all keys into lowercase strings
      h = {}
      hash.each { |k,v| h[k.to_s.downcase] = v }

      self.new(h['host'], h['path'], h['port'], h['proxy_host'], h['proxy_port'], h['user'], h['password'],
               h['use_ssl'], h['timeout'])
    end
```

http://www.ensta.fr/~diam/ruby/online/ruby-doc-stdlib/libdoc/xmlrpc/rdoc/classes/XMLRPC/Client.html

Comment: Yes Jeremy, I mentioned this in my question ... I know how new3 is defined. My question is if I **must** copy and paste the code within new3 to my derived class' constructor. It just doesn't make much sense to repeat the code, especially since it's within the class I'm deriving from. My question _is_ if this is the **only way**, if so, that's fine, I'll do it.

Comment: Where did I or anybody else say you _must_ copy and paste code? All you need to do is call `new3` inside your class method and return that instance. Just like the how `new3` calls `new`.

Comment: I'm not accusing anyone of said that ... I'm _asking_ if that's the case. The problem is that I _did_ call new3 but it keeps saying it is an undefined method.

Comment: Alright, thanks, so I take it there isn't really a way of doing what I wanted. No problem, I'll just re-use the code from within new3 in my derived class' initializer.

Comment: OK, so that brings me to ask: What's wrong with Arlen's answer? Do you still need access to the super class's `new3`?

Comment: To be honest, I'm confused. I don't understand how Arlen's answer is related to my question. he is saying 'client = XMLRPC::Client.new3', but client _is_ the class that I'm writing, do you understand my confusion? I don't know why my class should have a client given that it _is_ the client. I'm not saying it's wrong, I'm just confused.

Comment: It is awkward. What Arlen was saying is to create an instance in a class method and return it. It's a class method, which doesn't operate on a specific instance. But, after looking at this a bit more, this really is a limitation imposed by how `Client` is implemented with factory methods. You really would be better off copying the code in this case. The code is pretty straight forward, and really only serves to clean up the hash before calling the real constructor.

Comment: Yeah, I realize the code is pretty straightforward anyways, not a big deal, my purpose in posting this question was just to make sure that I wasn't going about it 'the wrong way', since Rubyists seem to preach DRY methods everywhere. I just went ahead and copied the code and everything works fine :) I just figured perhaps there was a 'trick' or something to go around this, but it's no big deal.

Comment: Yeah, it's unfortunate. Good luck.

Comment: `super` does work on subclasses. Calling new3 on a subclass will return an instance of that subclass: `Class.new(XMLRPC::Client).new3({})`. Overwriting `self.new3` in your subclass will allow you to use `super({})` to create an instance of the subclass.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be able to call `new3` on you subclass

```
class MyClient < XMLRPC::Client
end
MyClient.new3({})
```

Or overwrite it if you need to do extra stuff:

```
class MyClient < XMLRPC::Client
  def self.new3(args)
    client = super(args)
    # do some more stuff
    client
  end
end
MyClient.new3({})
```

Comment: Umm .. Sorry what? XMLRPC::Client already has that class method. The point of this question is to see if there's a way of /avoiding/ the work new3 already accomplishes.

Comment: So replace `new3` with `yourNew`, and `new` with `new3`. No?

Answer (score 1):

Make a new class method in your derived class (much like they did to make `new3` in the first place):

```
class MyDerived < XMLRPC::Client
    def self.new3(hashoptions)
         client = XMLRPC::Client.new3(hashoptions)
         # Do further initialisation here.
    end
end

myone = MyDerived.new3(:abc => 123, ...)
```

`super` only works in `initialize` (and only changes the parameters to the superclass's `initialize`), so it doesn't apply here.

Comment: Judging from these answers, I think my question is too misleading, I will re-state it. I don't mean that I want a new3 method in my derived class. Also, I'm deriving from XMLRPC::Client, so it doesn't make much sense to make it client =, or am I mistaken?

Comment: You basically need to create a factory method that returns an instance of the object you want, constructed the way you want. You cannot overload constructors in ruby the way you would in java, so you have to do this.

Comment: @Jorge: You do if it's a class method (note that it's `self.new3`). In this case, are you just wanting `MyDerived.new` to use `XMLRPC::Client.new3`? Just overload `self.new`, in that case.